# Add dynamic key in mongodb on update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to add a key with values or update the values if the key exists. 
At the moment I am doing this with 2 calls. I am getting the object and then i am altering it. It would like to be able to do this at once. My concern is that function is getting called twice in a short period of time and the second call would not get the updated object.

My Problem is that i am Adding a key to the object that is created by another webserver.

Is my approach dangerous? Will the second call wait for a completion of the update or do i have to block the db somehow?

How can I add a key on update that is part of an object? 
The Object with the data looks like this.

```js
{
key: "20170606000000$BgMKClY@$BgYEA10F@", 
value: {
        "quantity" : "0.3",
        "hourbooking_id" : "$BgECBlECDg@"
        }
}
```

The schema is the following:

```js
var Hours = new Schema({
    _id: ObjectId,
    hours: {}
});
```

My code looks like this:

```js
this.findHoursById = function(_id, callback){
    Hours.findOne({
        _id: _id
    }, function(err, chours){
        if(err || chours === null){
            callback({
                success: false,
                error: 'User not found'
            })
        }else{
            callback({
                success: true,
                error: 'none',
                hours: chours.hours
            });
        }
    })
};


this.addHours = function(_id, hours, callback){
    var insertHours = {};
    this.findHoursById(_id, function(result){
        if(result.success){
            insertHours = result.hours
        }
        insertHours[hours.key] = hours.value;
        var CHours =  new Hours({
            _id: _id
        });
        CHours.update({$set: {hours: insertHours}}, {upsert: true}, function(err, num, n){
            if (err){
                console.log(err);
                callback({ success: false, error: 'update hours error' });
                //throw err;
            }else{
                callback({ success: true, error: 'none' });
            }
        });
    });
};
```

the result should look like this

```js
{
"_id" : ObjectId("593e714b142174142c068a03"),
"hours" : {
    "20170612000000$Bg8HC1M@$BgECBVYP@" : {
        "quantity" : "0.5",
        "hourbooking_id" : "$Bg8FB1EPDw@"
    },
    "20170612000000$Bg8HC1M@$AQQCBV0C@" : {
        "quantity" : "1.1",
        "hourbooking_id" : "$Bg8KAFwECw@"
    }
},
"__v" : 0
}
```

and i want to update each the elemt with ObjectId("593e714b142174142c068a03")

to

```js
{
"_id" : ObjectId("593e714b142174142c068a03"),
"hours" : {
    "20170612000000$Bg8HC1M@$BgECBVYP@" : {
        "quantity" : "0.5",
        "hourbooking_id" : "$Bg8FB1EPDw@"
    },
    "20170612000000$Bg8HC1M@$AQQCBV0C@" : {
        "quantity" : "1.1",
        "hourbooking_id" : "$Bg8KAFwECw@"
    },
    "20170612000000$Bg8HC1M@$AQQCDDDC@" : {
        "quantity" : "1.1",
        "hourbooking_id" : "$Bg8KAFPPPw@"
    }

},
"__v" : 0
}
```

Ist this even a good idea? Or is it better to store the create a pair of objectid and new key like this?

```js
{
"user_id" : ObjectId("593e714b142174142c068a03"),
"comparekey : "20170612000000$Bg8HC1M@$BgECBVYP@" : 
"values" : {
        "quantity" : "0.5",
        "hourbooking_id" : "$Bg8FB1EPDw@"
},
"__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: Given a variable `_id` with the required value then: `Hours.findByIdAndUpdate(_id, { "$set": { "hours": insertHours }, { "upsert": true, "new": true },function(err, doc) {`. No need to create all of these operations since they already exist. See [`.findByIdAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) as the mongoose method and the general syntax of [`.findOneAndUpdate()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/) in the core MongoDB documentation.

Comment: the problem is that i want to update a subdocument by adding an id. Using your method i am overwriting hours and not appending the new key value pair

Comment: Edit your question to show an existing document and what you expect the resulting document to look like after the update, Also clarify what the actual data in requests looks like, since your response here suggests that there are in fact differently named keys in the target rather than the consistent names of "key" and "value" as your question states.